# how can i get stackoverflow's orange overlay at the top "First time here? Check out the FAQ" with the X button?

Tags: jquery

how can i get stackoverflow's overlay that appears at the very top ?

when i scroll up and down, it is very smooth.

how do i do this with jquery ?

Answer (score 6):

It's a fixed positioned element.

```
#foo { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 2; }

<div id="foo">
  <p>This is my fixed element!</p>
</div>
```

Then you can use [cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) to see if the user has visited before and show it with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

NOTE: The z-index on #foo must be higher than any elements that appear to be sitting on top of it.

Comment: Make sure you add a VALID DOCTYPE or IE7/8 will not support position: fixed.

Comment: problem is, sometimes the elements on the page covers the overlay....how to fix this ? 

also i dont get what u meant by valid doctype..... thank you.